# Subprocess– showing X lines of output

Tags: python, subprocess, output

I call a subprocess that runs an executable which outputs something like:

```
Header
some text
some text
--------------------------------
Progress:
***           | 30%
I want this line too
```

I would like the last three lines, but not the preceeding lines. The progress updates itself, something I would like to have too.

I currently do:

```
print subprocess.call('program {options}'.format(options=options), shell=True)
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `call` method is a wrapper around `Popen` which wait for the program to finish, which is probably not what you want here. Instead, you need to use `Popen` and read from it's `stdout`.

The answer depends a bit on what program you're using, or more specificity, how it's updating the terminal. Here is *one* solution, which should give you an idea on how to achieve this. You will probably need to adapt this.
For example, in my example, only the progressbar itself is actually updated. Your example might update more lines ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from __future__ import print_function
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['./out.py'], shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Discard first 4 lines
for i in range(4): proc.stdout.readline()

# First set of output
output = ''.join([ proc.stdout.readline() for i in range(3) ])
print(output.strip())
print('\n\n')

# Only one line is updated now
while True:
    output = proc.stdout.readline()

    print(output.strip().replace('\x1b[1A', ''))
```

As a reference, here's `out.py` which makes the progressbar

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from __future__ import print_function
import time, sys

print('Header')
print('some text')
print('some text')
print('-' * 40)
print('Progress:')
print('')
print('I want this line too')

sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1A' * 2)
i = 1
while True:
        if i > 40: break

        print('\r', '*' * i, sep='')
        sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1A')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        i += 1
        time.sleep(2)
```

### Bonus tip

In addition, you probably want to use the `subprocess` method with a list, like so:

```
subprocess.call(['ls', '-l', dir], shell=True)
```

The reason is that the arguments in the list will be escaped, and will still work even if they contain spaces, newlines, or any other unexpected characters. This is especially dangerous if you're using `shell=True`. If you can't pass the arguments as a list for some reason, then be sure to use the `shlex` module.